Почему selenium не работает с vivaldi?
Пытаюсь запустить vivaldi браузер через selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_driver_path = Service(r'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe')
browserBIN = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = browserBIN

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options, chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/")

Получаю ошибку совместимости хромдрайвера с версией хрома. Браузер на секунду открывается и сразу закрывается

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 128
Current browser version is 6.9.3447.44 with binary path C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Vivaldi\Application\vivaldi.exe



Хотя вивальди использует последнюю версию хромиума и маскируется тоже под неё же.

Вероятно, он читает это: https://i.sstatic.net/2aoFeFM6.png

@Qwertiy, я понимаю, но не знаю как это испрвить. В этом проблема

Проще всего - установить хром. Не понятно, почему вам для парсинга именно вивальди понадобился.
